# Change language of a string programmatically

Tags: android, localization

I have a `TextView` that displays a message to the user depending on the situation. I get the string to change depending on the situation and that's working great.

My problem is, how do I manage that for different languages?

I've looked around and most suggestions are to use a separate `string.xml` depending on the locale. But since this is only one string resource that changes its content programmatically it did not really work.

Is there a way to have something like

```
if(language is blabla)
    change the text to "this"
```

or something of the sort.

Comment: Different langauges, as in when the user changes their language settings? Or are you changing the language for just that one string based on some user selection within your app?

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically check the user's language by using class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html
i.e.

```
Locale.getDefault().toString()
```

Next you should use path to the appropriate string.xml
You only change bold part:

values-**en-rMU**

Answer (score 0):

I managed this by using SQLite database. I had 5 different tables for 5 languages. In my listAdapter I imported tables name from query:
   **SELECT * FROM dbname.sqlite_master WHERE type='table'**
Next, in one singleton class called OutputStrings I import all used strings for UI.
From each Activity Views are reading strings from OutputStrings.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change your local to your desired local:

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("en");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration mConfig = new Configuration();
    mConfig.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(mConfig, 
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```